# Proof that in a cyclic group an element of order d is a product of $\frac{n}{d}$d-cycles

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

I have to Proof that in a cyclic group of order n an element of order d is a product of $\frac{n}{d}$d-cycles. I know that the order of an element is d = $\frac{n}{gcd(n,m)}$. How can I conclude my thereom? Is there any proof for that?

Comment: As stated -- using ordinary definitions in group theory -- your stated 'theorem' doesn't quite make sense. Do you understand why?

Comment: I only want to check this for myself. It is quite interesting, because I do not know why this is true

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that in the Cayley representation of $G$, an element $g$ of order $d$ is a product of $\frac{n}{d}$ $d$-cycles, then this is clear, because the cycles are orbits of $x \mapsto gx$ and these are the cosets of the $\langle g \rangle$. The number of cosets is the index of $\langle g \rangle$, which is $\frac{n}{d}$.

Comment: Do you mean the number of unique cosets?

Comment: @Hans, yes.....